# What does "to line someone out" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

I occasionally hear this phrasal verb but never really understood what it means exactly. I fail to find a relevant definition anywhere. Oh yeah I'm familiar with the common usages of "line out" or "line something out" in construction, technology, etc. I use it all the time, but not in the same way as these examples

> Shortbread live rosin to help line me out! ([source](https://www.instagram.com/disheartened_aprn/p/CZS9ESXMHTM/?img_index=1))

> ...is probably one of the best people to help line me out on how freaked out I need to be about American democracy ([source](https://youtu.be/7YjY00Cd_MI?si=fuM9p5ZM1xVXRjoV&t=62))

Comment: How exactly do you use this?

Comment: @Lambie "Let's use the line out" or "Let's line out the amp" which in my line of work is fairly common.

Comment: I can make no sense of the first example. What on earth does rosin have to do with shortbread?

Comment: "Shortbread live rosin" seems to be a cannabis product. "Rosin" a variant of "resin" referring to cannabis resin.

Answer (score 1):

In the second quote

> ...is probably one of the best people to help **line me out** on how freaked out I need to be about American democracy

the meaning is

> **set me straight**

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/set-straight?q=set+someone+straight) has

> to tell someone the true facts about a situation that the person had not understood

Source: [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Line%20it%20out)

> **Line it out**
>
> To correct someone or a situation.
> *Tom was late for work and did not get his job done. So the boss had to line it out*

I have no idea what the first one means.

Comment: Any sources to back up "line me out" = "set me straight"? Because the meaning of "to set some straight" is not part of the question

Comment: Oh sorry, added the source.

Comment: Possibly related to "outline" and "[line out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/line%20out)" meaning "to indicate with or as if with lines".

Comment: @StuartF and in the sense of "I draw the line at ..."